# How do I create a formula for summing the product of cells, based on their value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of values. I want to add up the product of the two values, where the 2nd is grater than 1.

Now I'm using a separate 3rd column to aid in this and sumif the values based on the x2 column.

```
=SUMIF(B1:B9, ">0", C1:C9)
```

| X1 | X2 | Prod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 4 | 16 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 4 | 40 |

The result in this case should be 12+16+40 = 68

Is it possible to do the same without the 3rd column?

Comment: Pretty sure this has been answered numerous times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6)*(B2:B6)*(B2:B6>1))
```

Comment: or even just SUM()?

Comment: Fwiw, I think this answer is neater than the one I gave above ...

Comment: This will work on all versions of excel while Filter() will work only on Excel-365.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think it is a better answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think about the possibility to basically create and use an array with Boolean values

Comment: It's also been covered [numerous times before](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+excel+sum+value+based+on+value).

Comment: Somehow I missed them, probably because I searched for a too specific question, not a broad one

Answer (score 1):

Use the FILTER() function, using the 2nd column as the test.

=SUM(FILTER(A1:A5*B1:B5,B1:B5>1))

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that I have somehow missed before

```
=SUMPRODUCT( --(B1:B9 > 1), A1:A9, B1:B9)
```